# Detect Google Product attributes

Tags: feed, google-product-search

The [Google product attributes](http://support.google.com/merchants/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=188494#CH), such as `type`, `condition` and `availability` etc. are essential for the Google Product Search. You can submit them by using a [data feed](http://support.google.com/merchants/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=188494&topic=2473824&ctx=topic#CH).

I'm looking for a method, to **detect attributes** of a product that is not listed in my personal Google Merchant Center Account.

Is this possible ?